# SSIS and preferred data provider(ADO.NET, ODBC)

Tags: ssis

Now that Microsoft has officially declared OLE as  [passe.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlnativeclient/archive/2011/08/29/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access.aspx)  I'm curious as to what provider everyone likes to use.  I have a preference for ADO.NET but that's only because I can use variable names when I'm passing parameters to stored procs.  Should I start using ODBC instead?

Thanks

Comment: One issue that you will run into with SSIS 2008 is that the Lookup dataflow component works only with an OLEDB data source. We have had to use the lookup component extensively and so have had to standardize on OLEDB data sources for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I start using ODBC instead?

No, you want ADO.NET in .NET. If the database has an ADO.NET provider use that. ODBC is for native data access from unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old question but I feel that the accepted answer leaves a lot of information to be desired.

A lot of the components of SSIS either do not support ADO.NET connections or their ADO.NET counterpart is missing a lot of the functionality of the OLE DB version. I would actually recommend still using OLE DB with SSIS for this reason.

ADO.NET is better in a lot of ways but you'll find yourself in a world of hurt once you've got your whole solution setup with ADO.NET and find you cannot use some component or feature that you expected would work.

For example you cannot:

- Use an ADO.NET connection manager as a SQL Server Package Configuration source
- Set the query in an ADO.NET source via a package variable without setting it from outside the data flow. (OLE DB sources have the option in their native configuration window to set your query by a package variable.)
- As Brent mentioned in the comments of the question you cannot use the lookup transform with an ADO.NET source.

I'm sure there are more things that you cannot do in SSIS with an ADO.NET connection but I haven't run across them yet. But IMHO there are already enough drawbacks to outweigh the benefits of using ADO.NET in SSIS until it gets more support in the tooling.